# Java co-routine alternative for stopping execution of a method based on a timer?

Tags: java, libgdx, coroutine

I'm quite new to LibGDX, I have some experience with C# when it comes to game development, however I'm trying to get my head around how to properly add a delay; for example, adding a fire rate to a weapon, so that even if the player where to click multiple times, it limits how often the shoot method is called.  in C# we would create a co-routine with a timer which changes a boolean once complete, to set the flag so a method can be called, but there are no co-routines in Java really. so far i've been trying to use this:

```
 Timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    clip -= 1;
                    isShooting = false;
                }
            }, this.fireRate);
```

reload delay:

```
Timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Reload();
                }
            }, this.reloadSpeed);
```

these are within an abstract class, and the speeds are set within the extended classes constructors and never change; this works for the first clip, the fire rate, but after that none of the delays work; reloading or fire rate. While it does work slightly, As stated above i'm quite new to this, so i'm very open to a better method or fix!

Comment: So libgdx isn't an event based framework with a main game loop? Never used it, but it seems very weird to use timers in a game in such a manner. Isn't it much easier to simply store when the last shot was fired and check for that in your fire method? At least that's more how I'd have done it in the good old days. (Timers for one can have really mad accuracy. 15ms at its best, but on mobile platforms it can be much worse for battery conservation reasons).

Comment: This sounds like a good idea; i'll give it a go! It sounds much more accurate, so thanks!

Comment: Timers also have a bug on Android if the game is started twice, so avoid them and go with the render() (or act()) method's delta.